# How to perform crossover in a 2-dimensional array - genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, genetic-algorithm, mutation, crossover

I have the following two chromosomes which are represented as a 2D array.

```
// First chromosome
[
  [ 12 45 23 ]
  [ 34 01 89 ]
  [ 33 90 82 ]
]

// Second chromosome
[
  [00 45 89 ]
  [00 00 34 ]
]
```

The constraints on the chromosome are that each array in the chromosome array must remain together. For example in the first chromosome `[ 12 45 23 ]` must remain together. With this in mind, I believe the way to perform crossover with the above chromosome structure is to randomly select a horizontal crossover point. such as the following:

```
// First produced off-spring
[
  [ 12 45 23 ] // First chromosome
  [ 00 00 34 ] // Second chromosome
]

// Second produced off-spring
[
  [ 00 45 89 ] // Second chromosome
  [ 34 01 89 ] // First chromosome
  [ 33 90 82 ] // First chromosome
]
```

Is this the correct way to perform mutation on a 2D chromosome array which rows must remain intact? If this is, does this method have a specific name? Or would this come under `One-point` crossover?

Comment: It is very dependant of the problem, which you are solving. Without this information it will be difficult to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this method have a specific name? Or would this come under One-point crossover?

In various papers about variable length genetic algorithms it's called *one point crossover*.

For variable length chromosomes one point crossover is often proposed in a more general way: you can select a distinct crossover point for each chromosome. E.g.

```
C1 = [ A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6]

C2 = [ B1, B2, B3, B4]
```

Choosing crossover point `1` for `C1` and `3` for `C2` you get:

```
C1 = [ A1 | A2, A3, A4, A5, A6]

C2 = [ B1, B2, B3 | B4]


C1' = [A1 B4]
C2' = [B1, B2, B3, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6]
```

This allows the chromosome length to start growing. Depending on the specific problem it could be a requirement or just bloating (in both cases you may need to account for that in the fitness function).

> Is this the correct way to perform mutation on a 2D chromosome array which rows must remain intact?

It's a simple method (so a good one). [Uniform crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)#Uniform_crossover) is another simple approach.

[Synapsing Variable-Length Crossover: Meaningful Crossover for Variable-Length Genomes](https://www.academia.edu/26499933/Synapsing_Variable-Length_Crossover_Meaningful_Crossover_for_Variable-Length_Genomes) (Benjamin Hutt and Kevin Warwick, IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation, vol. 11, no. 1, february 2007) describes other interesting (more complex) possibilities.

The *best* crossover is very **problem specific**.